# powerbuilder.net dropdown datawindow

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder.net

Im developing a small system using powerbuilder.net. im not that good at powerbuilder classics before but i was able to get through just by reading in the infocenter. now my question is, back in powerbuilder classic, you can determine or put a static value on dropdown datawindow. i mean, you can put the value and the text just within the painter.

i guess, pb.net doesnt have this feature because i have searched through the control properties and infocenter to find it but no luck. please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are talking about the "Drop Down List", edit style v.s. the "Drop Down Datawindow" edit style. The drop down list lets you type in hard coded code table of data value and display value.

So, when editing the datawindow, select the column you want the drop down list, and choose the drop down list edit style in properties. After that the properties section will display a table for you to enter one to many code values and display values.  Oh, welcome to Stack Overflow.